# Execute HTML code contained in a variable

Tags: html, pug

I have a string variable that contain HTML code and I want it to render instead of displaying it as text. I tried different Pug configurations :
If the variable `content` contains the string `<a href="/something">@something</a>` :

```
p(style="white-space: pre-line")
    | #{content}
```

displays the string as text and doesn't render it,

```
p(style="white-space: pre-line")
    #{content}
```

display this : `<@something>@something>` with the first @something being clickable,

```
p(style="white-space: pre-line")
    #[content]
```

and this returns an error.
Is there a possible way to do this ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply replace the hash of `#{content}` with an exclamation mark: `!{content}`. This is called [unescaped string interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html#string-interpolation-unescaped) and should render your content without escaping HTML tags:

```
p(style="white-space: pre-line")
    | !{content}
```